# enable gzip module on wampserver

Tags: apache, gzip, deflate

I want enable Gzip module on wamp server and i open two mod in httpd.conf

```
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
```

some configs at bottom

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .(?:exe|t?gz|zip|bz2|sit|rar)$ no-gzip dont-vary 
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .(?:pdf|mov|avi|mp3|mp4|rm)$ no-gzip dont-vary
</IfModule>
```

But I can't see "content-encoding:gzip" in response header..

server : windows server 2003
apache : 2.4.4

thanks

Answer (score 13):

code in .htaccess file in the root directory .Try this , it worked for me

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|html|php|txt|xml)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: is this in addition to the code in question or standalone?

Comment: This should be marked as a correct answer!!! Thank you, @Andy

Answer (score 2):

You may also need to set configs in `.htaccess` as well.

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  # Specify file types in case necessary
</IfModule>
```